# Why do I care about a count of unactionable posts in the top bar?

Tags: support

There's always been a counter at the top of the page, and it seemed to indicate that there was something that needed to be reviewed, with the color indicating what. However, shortly after the roll-out of the new top bar, it seems to have settled on a lovely sienna, with the explanatory text "total posts awaiting review". For example, right now I see (I'm talking about the "21"):

[image]

Yet, there isn't actually anything for me to do. If I click it, I get:

[image]

There seems to be no action I can take to make this notification go away, and it's been there for weeks. Consequently, I've learned to ignore it.

Can this counter either go back to counting things *I could do*, or could it just go away entirely? It serves absolutely no purpose that I can find, except to remind me that "there are posts that are pending something, from someone", which is perpetually true, and thus irrelevant.

Comment: Possibly `by-design`, see [Review counts in the top-bar and /review don't match](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match) on [meta.se].

Comment: That said, I absolutely agree that *at least* it's counter-intuitive.

Comment: Then I vote for no indicator at all. Though, I do wonder what happened to the old indicator, which I could make go away through action.

Comment: If you are seeing the indicator there all the time, and it doesn't change... that's a rather strange bug. I don't see the indicator at all at the moment - do you?

Comment: @Oded I do, on the main site. [ham.se] (And it shows 21 for me too, which I checked and definitely was not accurate.)

Comment: I see exactly 21 posts in the different review queues on the main site. Don't know why I didn't see it earlier!

Comment: @Oded It changes...the trouble is that many of the things I have already reviewed. Thus, there's nothing *I* can do to make that notification go away. And in practice, it's always there (although the number changes), so I ignore it.

Comment: I understand the frustration. Not sure what the plans on this are though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should care because it means that you're pulling your weight but others are not. We *could* hide the number... but that'd still mean that 21 posts were sitting there, needing attention, for *days*, and no one was responding. If you're the only one on the site who cares enough about this stuff to notice, then pretending it doesn't exist just hides the problem from the one person who might actually *do* something about it!

I just went through the review queues here and cleared out everything that remained. There were posts that'd been sitting there for *months*... This is not a good sign!

If you see this again, consider letting the moderators know about it, or posting something here on meta requesting that others jump in to help clear out the backlog.